# command prompt getting closed on its own using os.system

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pytest

I am using `os.system(cmd)` to launch a command prompt and run a command in it. Now, this command is command to run a `py.test` code. But the command prompt is getting closed on its own immediately after py.test gets executed. I found that adding `&& pause` at the end of cmd helps retain the command prompt till I press any button. But this is working fine only if all test cases pass in my `py.test`. So, how do I retain the command prompt whatever happens with the cmd.

This is my basic idea of my project: I have many `py.test` modules. I want to run any of these with just one command wherein I specify the module I want to run. For this purpose I am opening different command prompt and running my module there.

Comment: replace `&&` (conditional execution: run if previous command didn't fail) with `&` (command concatenation operator)

Comment: You don't need `os.system` or any instance of cmd.exe to run a Python script and keep the console open (i.e. conhost.exe -- not cmd.exe, which is just a shell). It may be more convenient to use `subprocess.call('python -im pytest "%s"' % script_path)`. After the script is done, Python starts the interactive REPL, which may be helpful for further analysis, but I've never used py.test to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot MC ND. It worked like a miracle.

Comment: I came to know about subprocess only from your comment eryksun. Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: Can you put your answers below so that I can accept your answers.

Comment: @KalyanamRajashree, answering your own question isn't discouraged.